# Flex eclipse plugin isn't it free?

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, flexbuilder, flash-builder

Eclipse is free , flex sdk is free. Is not the eclipse plugin for flex free?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is not free.

There are some free options for development, however:

- Command-line and editor of choice
- [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Main_Page)
- [Tofino](http://www.ensemble.com/products/tofino.shtml) (Visual Studio plugin, if you already have that)

Answer (score 5):

I guess you mean Flash Builder (formerly Flex Builder).

It is an Eclipse-based IDE, so I guess you can call it an Eclipse plugin, but it is not free.

You can however get a free license for it if you are unemployed or student, or using it for academic purposes.

Check http://www.adobe.com/devnet-archive/flex/free/ out to know more about this offer.

Comment: i thought flex builder and flex eclipse plugin were two different things ?

Comment: @user No, there is Flash Builder and that's it. Flex Builder is the old name.

Answer (score 4):

There a two flavors of Flash Builder (formerly Flex Builder). The Flash Builder plugin for eclipse and the Flash Builder stand-alone (build upon eclipse). Both are part of the commercial license.

Beside the commercial Flash Builder plugin there exist many other [commercial plugins](http://phoenix.eclipse.org/community/commercialplugins.php) for eclipse. Nothing confusing about that.

Comment: I am not quite agreeing with you. There is basically no difference between the plugin and the stand-alone: the stand-alone is just the plugin running on a separate Eclipse provided at the installation.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be some confusion here if I'm understanding correctly.

There is a free flex plug-in avilable for eclipse.  Flex has been an open-source project and the SDK available as a stand-alone plug-in for the eclipse IDE for free; yes for free, for several years now.  For obvious reasons it isn't widely promoted, but it is available.  Here is a link explaining the free flex 4 SDK for Eclipse.

[Free flex SDK explaination](http://www.seanhsmith.com/2010/03/29/flex-for-free-setting-up-the-flex-4-sdk-with-eclipse-ide/)

Comment: Your link is not related to your answer. If it is available, why won't you post a proper link?